# statatics problem

Tags: probability

Ken is considering entering a local fishing​ tournament, but his choice to enter depends somewhat on whether his​ rival, Billy, will enter the same fishing tournament. Ken thinks that he has a $0.4$ probability of winning the fishing tournament if Billy does not enter the​ tournament, and a $0.15$ probability of winning if Billy does enter the fishing tournament.

If the probability that Billy enters the fishing tournament is $0.40​$,

​a) find the probability that Ken wins the fishing tournament.

​b) If Ken does not win the fishing​ tournament, what is the probability that Billy did not enter the​ tournament?

I've trying to set up tree diagram, but does not work in either way need help!